# QtCore4.dll procedure entry points couldnt be located

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dll, migration

I am migrating a project from Qt 4.x to Qt5, I have finished migrating the code but the resulting exe requires certain libraries which are giving me some problems. I have put the .dll's needed in the same folder as the .exe, and until now I have provided succesfully all the libraries that it requested, but now I cant seem to find the appropriate QtCore4.dll.

Without any DLL in the same folder & using the DLL found at System32 & using the DLL downloaded from dll-files I get the same next error:

```
The procedure entry point _Z11qUncompressPKhi could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

Using the DLL found at C:/Qt/4.8.5/bin I get:

```
The procedure entry point _??1QVariant@QAE@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library QtCore4.dll
```

I have tried putting each one of them in System32 and didnt solve anything.
Also when I execute the next command in the command line:

```
regsvr32 QtCore4.dll
```

I get:

> The module "QtCore4.dll" may not be compatible with the version of
>   Windows that you're running. Check if the module is compatible with an
>   x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of regsvr32.exe

My system type is x64 bits.

I hope I provided enough information on the issue, if I missed something please tell me.
Thankyou.

Comment: If you port to Qt5, why do you need QtCore4.dll which is Qt4 dll?

Comment: @vahancho I have wondered the same thing, it doesnt make sense, but the exe will not run without it. My best guess is that computer science isnt an exact science.

Comment: You must have somehow used old object files or libraries that are still compiled for Qt 4. Do a proper clean and thoroughly check that everything is in fact compiled for Qt5

Comment: Computers are pretty predictable, but they require consistency in what we want to do with them. If you build Qt5 application you need Qt5 dlls - that is easy.

Comment: I will try to migrate the used libraries to Qt5 and see if that works, I hope it does because migrating is a pain in the arse X_X